# Scripting with Raycast and hitObject (using C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, hololens

Scripting error in Unity. C# beginner, where am I going wrong?

Here is the error:

```
Assets\Scripts\InteractHelper.cs(44,30): error CS0103: The name 'hitObject' does not exist in the current context
```

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class InteractHelper : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Material MaterialInGaze;
    private Material _oldMaterial;
    private GameObject _objectInFocus;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        var ray = new Ray(Camera.main.transform.position,
            Camera.main.transform.forward);
        RaycastHit raycastInfo;

        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out raycastInfo))
        {
            var hitObject = raycastInfo.transform.gameObject;
            if (hitObject == _objectInFocus)
                return;

            var renderer = hitObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();
            if (renderer == null)
                return;
            _oldMaterial = renderer.material;
            renderer.material = MaterialInGaze;
            _objectInFocus = hitObject;
        }
        else
        {
            if (_objectInFocus == null)
                return;

            var renderer = _objectInFocus.GetComponent<Renderer>();
            renderer.material = _oldMaterial;
            _objectInFocus = hitObject;
        }
    }
}
```

I am following a tutorial (its a bit outdated now) but my code matches theirs exactly.
I'm just learning C#

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Replace the final line `_objectInFocus = hitObject`
with  `_objectInFocus = null`

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening in the last line of your else statement, right here:

```
        _objectInFocus = hitObject;
```

This error is happening because hitObject is declared in your if statement, while this code is in your else statement; since they are in different parts of your code, it can't tell that hitObject has been declared.

The best fix for this would be to declare hitObject right before the if statement.

For example, the new code would be

```
    ... 

    RaycastHit raycastInfo;

    var hitObject = raycastInfo.transform.gameObject;

    if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out raycastInfo))
    {

    ...
```

instead of having hitObject in the same area. Always declaring it to null will result in unwanted behavior.